# How to only allow WPF Window's height resizable?

Tags: c#, wpf

To be specific, I have a `Window` whose `Content` is set as a `UserControl`. And I would like to allow users to drag to increase the height of the `Window`, but the `Width` should be fixed and non-resizable. I guess I have such properties to modify but I can't make them behave as I desired:

- `Window.SizeToContent`, available values: Manual, Width, Height,
- WidthAndHeight `Window.ResizeMode`, available values: CanMinimize,
  CanResize, CanResizeWithGrip , NoResize
- and of course the Min/Max of Height, Width of the `UserControl`

But what kind of combination can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do that would be to set both `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` of the window to the same value:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication20.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" MinWidth="525" MaxWidth="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to do it in code-behind, as you wrote in your comment, you could do it as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication20.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350">
    <Rectangle x:Name="childElement"  Width="525" Fill="Red">

    </Rectangle>
</Window>
```

And in the window's constructor, you would write:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Binding binding = new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = childElement };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, MinWidthProperty, binding);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, MaxWidthProperty, binding);

}
```

Please note: the `childElement` above would be your UserControl.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if I don't want the `Window` to be set any height/width values? Because the `Window` is a wrapper for different `UserControl` (actually I don't even have a XAML file for the `Window`. I generate a Window object in the code-behind)

Comment: Thanks! I needed to do some twist because I used a `DataTemplate` to generate the `UserControl` from my ViewModel (so no childElement available for the `Window`) but finally made it work

Answer (score 0):

Using the [WindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.windowchrome.resizeborderthickness.aspx) property, this can be achieved in a much simpler fashion without having to use MinWidth, MaxWidth and ActualHeight properties.
For example, consider the following style that you can use with your window to allow resizing height only:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="YourResourceDictionaryClass" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell">

<Style x:Key="AllowResizeHeightOnlyWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
<Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <shell:WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="0, 2"
                            />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps